# Total number of "yes" rows in Data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a few tables with "billable" rows that have the data fill in as y or n (being yes or no). I understand how to add the total price amount of a column, but not how to count rows that contain 'y'. For example below, I'm finding the first row, getting the length and alerting the total.

**HTML**

```
<table id='pricetable'>
    <tr>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Billable</th>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>201</td>
        <td>y</td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>y</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>n</td>
    </tr>      
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
// initiate table
oPrice = $('#pricetable').dataTable();


var priceTotal = 0;

// iterate through each input and add to sum
$('#pricetable td:nth-child(1)').each(function () {
    var dataArray = oPrice._('td:nth-child(1)');
    for (var i = 0, len = dataArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        priceTotal += +dataArray[i];
    }
});

// alert total
alert(priceTotal);
```

I need to also alert the number of billable rows... so something like

```
var billTotal = 0;
            $("#pricetable td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
                var val = $(this).text();
                if (val == 'y') reimTotal++;
                billTotal++;
            });
            //alert(billTotal); //count is 2

            // change value of summary total
            $('#myBillable').val(billTotal);
```

...but the issue is that this needs to okay with Datatables. If you change the number of rows, you'll notice I have 6 rows, and 4 billable - but it only alerts 3. Anyway, the price totals work just fine for me but I need to know how to total the billable rows. Thanks in advance! UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1555/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add all billable rows you can use .DataTable().rows().eq(0) and apply a filter like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table=$('#pricetable').DataTable({//use DataTable instead to use .rows()
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", 
        "iDisplayLength": 5
    });   
    var priceTotal = 0;
    table.rows().eq(0).filter( function (row) {//each row inside the .DataTable
        if(table.cell(row,1).data() === 'y'){//if it is billable
           priceTotal+=parseInt(table.cell(row,0).data());//parse the data to int and sum
        }
    });  
    alert("price "+priceTotal);
});
```

you need to use .DataTable() to return a DataTables API instance so you can access each row with .rows() and loop to add only the billable rows
http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/

Comment: Very close. I just need to alert the number of billable rows. Here, it's 4 but I might have 500. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/1/

Comment: to get the number of billable rows just add myBillable++ inside the filter function [http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/4/)

Comment: This is working in the fiddle, but regardless of what I do on my project, I'm getting "Undefined is not a function" on the table.rows().eq(0).filter(function (row) line. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe the version of datatables i used the first version you put on the fiddle 1.10.2

Comment: Using Datatables 1.9.4, jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: Datatables 1.9.4 does not have the .rows function so you need to do something similar with the legacy api [https://legacy.datatables.net/api](https://legacy.datatables.net/api)

Comment: Using the new 1.10 breaks my tables, and I don't want to break everyone else's work. How could I implement this with 1.9.4? http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/15/

Comment: with 1.9 you can do something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1560/](http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1560/)

Comment: My datatable init is wrapped in a $.getJSON statement, which makes var table not longer a variable after the statement ends "table is not defined". How can I fix this?

Comment: And if i store the code within the function, the total comes out as 0.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/doniyor/Vc96L/ this should work for you.

```
$(function () {
 var count = 0;
 $("#pricetable").find("td").each(function () {
    var val = $(this).text();
    if (val == 'y') count++;
 });
 alert(count);
});
```

Comment: The issue is that Datatables isn't initiated for whatever reason in the fiddle. This code shows up as '0' on my end.

Comment: @triplethreat77 then you have another problem, the code works just fine for me.

Comment: Because you don't have Datatables initiated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your loop to iterate all TDs like so:

```
$('#pricetable td').each(function (index) {
    var item = $(this).text();
    if (index % 2 == 0)
        priceTotal += parseFloat(item);
    else if (item == "y")
        billableCount++;
});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3t6t/1/)

Comment: Dave, the issue is that Datatables aren't initiated for whatever reason in the fiddle. This code shows up as '0' on my end. Also, I have 12 columns, and numerous have y/n so I'm sticking with the nth-child selector to specify column.

Comment: $('#pricetable td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
        var item = $(this).text();
        if (item == "y")
            billableCount++;
    });

Comment: The code above would be closer to what I need, but it does show as zero.